# How to set the database for AuthComponent in CakePHP 2.4?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

I am current writing a database access application using CakePHP (version 2.4). For security reason, I am only given the right to read the database ("data database"). Therefore, I have no choice but to use another database ("application database") for my login system and some other application data.

This is a database accessing application, over 80% of my code is related to data database and therefore I want to keep my default database connection to data database. For model written by myself, I know I can set the database to be used by:

```
public $useDbConnect = $applicationDatabase;
```

$loginDatabase is the database configuration to my application database. It is added to the configuration already.

The problem is, I was using the authComponent of Cakephp for my login system, and the default of this component is to use the default database connection. So, when I called

```
$this->Auth->loggedIn(); //to check if the user have logged in or not
```

in any controller, it gives a error code saying:

```
Error: Call to a member function loggedIn() on a non-object
```

I found the actual problem when I called AuthComponent in my user controller:

```
$this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
```

This is the line for hash password before save (and is also used in official guide on cakephp official site.) And it gives the following error:

> Missing Database Connection
>
> Error: A Database connection using "Mysql" was missing or unable to connect.
>   The database server returned this error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_connection.ctp

So, back to the question: is there a way to change the database setting used for AuthComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to resolve the `Error: Call to a member function loggedIn() on a non-object`, you need to add `$components = array('Auth', 'Session');` to your AppController.

To answer your next question, the AuthComponent does not set a database config to authenticate a user. It will use the database table used by the 'User' model. 
Thus, add the following to your User.php model:

```
public $useDbConfig = 'loginDatabase';
```

Make sure you have a database with the `users` table populated with username and password. Also, as mentioned in your question, add the loginDatabase config correctly to the `Config/database.php` file.

```
public $loginDb = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'somehost',
    'login' => 'someusername',
    'password' => 'somepassword',
    'database' => 'login_database', //this database should have your users table
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that points to the exact problem. I have added the $components = array('Auth', 'Session'); in my AppController as it is used in every controller, but it turns out that my teammates deleted it accidentally when migrating to his local server.

Comment: And for the database problem, it is similar situation. My teammate added a direct sql call to the database and set the Database configuration by hand in that function. That's why adding public $useDbConfig = 'loginDatabase'; didn't work.